# http live streaming：i can't cache my ts files

Tags: ios, caching, http-live-streaming

My m3u8 file is below:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXTINF:11,
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="static.key1",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000001
/hls/test/test-1.ts
#EXTINF:11,
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="static.key2",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000002
/hls/test/test-2.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

What i want is:after playing it once,ts files can be cached in client end.
I observed the process in my nginx log. When I replay it ,ts files access logs still can be seen.

it seems that "#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES" doesn't work.

Is there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should also check the Cache-Control and Expires http headers to see if they're instructing the client to cache.

Allowing cache is not the same as forcing cache... Likely, the client won't cache regardless of what you do on the server, but it's almost certain to only cache when both the playlist and the http server recommend it.